# wrapper around my .Rmd file to take input path and name of output file

Tags: r, bash, sh

I have written a code of few hundred lines in Rmarkdown. I would like this script to take the input path and name of the output file from the user through a wrapper. I am very new to this kind of coding and my question is how can I have a wrapper that will take these two inputs and parse it to my .Rmd file.

As an example here are first few lines of my .Rmd file.

````
---
title: "QC Report"
author: "Angelo"
output: 
  html_document:
  css: style.css
  toc: true
  fontsize: 15pt
---

  For the current QC report we first refer to the 10x QC reports for initial sequence and mapping quality metrics.


#1. Loading of libraries 


```{r include = T}
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(scater))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(mvoutlier))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(Rtsne))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(limma))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ggplot2))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(repr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(cowplot))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(knitr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(rmarkdown))
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```


#2. Loading expression data

\newline



```{r include = T}

  loadSCE <- function(path){
  sce <- read10XResults(path)
  #sce <- normalize(sce) # Data normalization based on scran

  mitochondrialGenes <- as.character(rowData(sce)[startsWith(rowData(sce)$symbol, "mt-"),]$id)

  isSpike(sce, "MT") <- rownames(sce) %in% mitochondrialGenes

  sce <- calculateQCMetrics(sce, 
                            feature_controls = list(
                              MT =  isSpike(sce, "MT")
                            ))
}

```



```{r include = T}

paths <- list.dirs(path = "/home/mydir/SampleData/", recursive = FALSE)


for (i in 1:length(paths))
  assign(paste0("sce_",i), loadSCE(paths[i]))


sce=0
for (i in 1:length(paths))
 sce[i]<-print(noquote(paste0("sce_",i)))

```

```{r include = T}
    t_list <- mget(ls(pattern="sce_\\d+"))
     for(i in seq_along(t_list))
 {
 metadata(t_list[[i]])["name"] <- paste0("iMates-",i)
}
```
````

In essence what I would like is something like this:

```
wrapper.sh -path /home/mydir/  -outfile output.html

or 

Raw.Rmd -p /home/mydir/  -outfile output.html
```

Please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do these things with an R script, run using something like `Rscript script.R /home/mydir/ output.html` (or on some operating systems, with a hash-bang script like below).

The file `script.R` should contain the code to get the arguments from the command line and pass them to `rmarkdown::render`.  This would do it:

```
#! /path/to/Rscript --vanilla --default-packages=utils,rmarkdown
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
path <- args[1]
outfile <- args[2]

render("doc.Rmd", output_file = outfile, params = list(path = path))
```

This keeps `doc.Rmd` fixed as the name of the document.  It will need to declare that `path` is a parameter; add this to your YAML header:

```
params: 
  path: "."
```

The string `"."` is the default value if you don't specify a path.

To retrieve the path from the parameters, a code chunk like this would do it:

````
```{r}
path <- params$path
```
````

Then just use `path` like any other variable in your code chunks.

Comment: Hi, What should I put in this line of the code:  paths <- list.dirs(path = "/home/mydir/SampleData/", recursive = FALSE)

Comment: You asked how to get `/home/mydir` into the document; I showed you that.   It will end up in the variable `path` if you follow my suggestion. What you do with it is up to you.